# Repeated Undeliverable email in outlook mailbox for salesforce contact user

Tags: email

I have outlook mailbox integrated from salesforce service cloud application for mail delivery from salesforce aplication to cuatomer email conatct.

Everyday i am getting lots of undelivered mail into my outlook mailbox for few customer email address.

This is being repeated again agian.

mail format:

"FW: ** Process from archive manually ** Undeliverable: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
fromAddressStart:xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com:fromAddressEnd fromNameStart:xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com:fromNameEnd mailboxStart:xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com:mailboxEnd 
Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:
xxx

The recipient's e-mail address was not found in the recipient's e-mail system. Microsoft Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you. Please check the e-mail address and try resending this message, or provide the following diagnostic text to your system administrator.